# Assign several numbers to a boost vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector

Assume I want to assign a list of 3 numbers to a vector v such that v[0] is the first element of the list, v[1] the second and v[2] the third.
I found out that for the standard vector template there is the assign library of boost

```
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp> // for 'operator+=()'
using namespace boost::assign; // bring 'operator+=()' into scope

int main {
    vector<int> values;  
    values += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9; // insert values at the end of the container
}
```

Now when I try to do this for a boost vector

```
boost::numeric::ublas::vector<int> values
values += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
```

it tells me 'no operator "+=" matches these operands. How do I solve this with boost vectors? (I assume it must be something simple but I'm too daft to see it)

Comment: that's a horrible syntax. doesn't look a good idea to me.

Comment: Have you actually read the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#extensions)?

Comment: "I assume it must be something simple but I'm too daft to see it" - you'd have to write an overload of the `operator+=()` which takes the appropriate arguments and returns the appropriate type suitable for chaining. Since you meed some insight into `boost` to do this for the above I expect this might not be as simple as you might think. Plus, as Karoly already stated, it's horrible syntax - there must be a more intuitive way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this might be to use the stream insertion operator.

```
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp> // for 'operator+=()'
#include <boost/assert.hpp> 
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/assignment.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign; // bring 'operator+=()' into scope

int main()
{
    boost::numeric::ublas::vector<int> values(9);
    values <<= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
    BOOST_ASSERT( values.size() == 9 );
    BOOST_ASSERT( values[0] == 1 );
    BOOST_ASSERT( values[8] == 9 );
    std::cout << values << std::endl;
}
```

Result is that the program prints:

```
[9](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Unfortunately, it will core dump if you don't already have the vector sized appropriately, so that's a potential drawback to this method.  I had originally posted an answer that said to use `push_front( values ) = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;` but then I tried it and was surprised to learn that this boost vector does not have either a `push_front` or `push_back` operator.

An ugly alternative would be to both set and use the underlying data representation of the boost vector, but this is rather hackish!

```
    boost::numeric::ublas::vector<int, std::vector<int>> values;
    push_back(values.data()) = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
```

This sets the underlying data representation to be `std::vector<int>` and then uses the Boost `assign` library to make the syntax in the second line possible.